# Show solvability of ODE without explicitly calculating solution

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Show that 
$$
 u + u^{(4)} - u^{(2)} = f
$$
has a solution $u \in H^4(\mathbb R)$ (without explicitly calculuting it) for every $f \in L^2(\mathbb R)$!

What criteria for solvability for such ODE's exist?

Comment: What does H mean?

Comment: $H^k(\mathbb R) := \{ u \in \mathbb L^2(\mathbb R) : D^a u \in L^2(\mathbb R), 0 \le a \le k \}$, see http://www.unc.edu/math/Faculty/met/chap4.pdf

Comment: I would add the tag "functional analysis". You could ask the question: When the linear differential operator $D: H^4(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow L^2(\mathbb{R})$ given by $D(u)=u+u^{(4)}-u^{2}$ is surjective?

Answer (score 2):

One general method  is to recognize the differential equation as the [Euler-Lagrange equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation) for some functional. If the functional is differentiable and attains its minimum somewhere, the point of minimum is a solution of the differential equation.

The fact that your differential equation is linear indicates that the functional must be quadratic. Observe that the term $(u^{(k)})^2$ in the functional contributes $2(-1)^ku^{{2k}}$ to the equation, via 
$$\int ((u+\varphi)^{(k)})^2-\int  u^{(k)} = 
 2\int  u^{(k)}\varphi^{(k)} + o(\|\varphi\|) =  2(-1)^k\int  u^{(2k)}\varphi +o(\|\varphi\|)$$
(Integration by parts $k$ times). This leads to the functional 
$$
F(u) = \int (u'')^2 + (u')^2 + u^2 -fu 
$$
(Check that the Euler-Lagrange equation is what you have.)

This is a convex functional bounded from below, to which standard methods of the calculus of variations apply: see the relevant chapter of *Partial Differential Equations* by Evans, for example.

Comment: This method seems to show existence of weak solutions in $H^2(\mathbb R)$ only.

Comment: @daw Initially, yes. Then the regularity improves thanks to the ODE, which expresses the fourth derivative it terms of lower orders.

Comment: This is a non-trivial conclusion as there is no fourth derivative to start with.